# EINVAL with gpfs_fcntl

Tags: c++, c, filesystems

I'm trying to use prefetching hints on an IO-heavy code. I set up the code according to my understanding of the man page of gpfs_fcntl(), but do get an EINVAL. I'm a bit lost now what I'm doing wrong - any hints are appreciated.

Mount: `/dev/scratch16 on /bgscratch type gpfs (rw,dev=cadmos-gss.gss1a:scratch16,ldev=scratch16)`

```
Error: Prefetch using gpfs_fcntl failed: Invalid argument (22), 32768b at 7713095680 from /bgscratch/foo.dat
```

File: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 delalond bbp 14739308544 Jul 25  2012 /bgscratch/foo.dat`

Source:

```
void BufferedFile::prefetch( const uint64_t offset, const uint64_t size )
{
   if( file_.fd == -1 )
       file_.fd = ::open( filename.c_str(), O_RDONLY );
   if( file_.fd == -1 )
   {
       LBWARN << "open() failed: " << lunchbox::sysError << std::endl;
       return;
   }
   struct
   {
       gpfsFcntlHeader_t hdr;
       gpfsAccessRange_t acc;
   } arg;
   arg.hdr.totalLength = sizeof(arg);
   arg.hdr.fcntlVersion = GPFS_FCNTL_CURRENT_VERSION;
   arg.hdr.fcntlReserved = 0;
   arg.acc.structLen = sizeof(arg.acc);
   arg.acc.structType = GPFS_ACCESS_RANGE;
   arg.acc.start = offset;
   arg.acc.length = size;
   arg.acc.isWrite = 0;
   if( gpfs_fcntl( file_.fd, &arg ) != 0 )
        LBWARN << "Prefetch using gpfs_fcntl failed: " << lunchbox::sysError
               << ", " << size << "b at " << offset << " from " << filename
               << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: I could reproduce the problem in a standalone application, and the error happens once start in greater than 4GB, even though it is a long long and a 64 bit system.

Comment: you should add the language tag so more people will see it. wasn't sure if it was c or c++ so i didn't added any

Comment: Did you initialize file_.fd to -1 ?

Comment: Yes, fd is initialized to -1 in the constructor.

Comment: My guess would be that you need to open the file handle using something other than the bog standard "open" ... just a guess though, sorry :(

Comment: Looking at `gpfsAccessRange_t` the elements `start` and `length` are of type `offset_t` is this equivalent to `uint64_t` on your platform?

Comment: start and length are long long in my gpfs_fcntl.h

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read after the end of file.

Given the `fileSize`, try something like

```
arg.acc.length = fileSize > offset + size ? size : fileSize - offset;
```

Comment: 32768b at 7713095680 for a file of length 14739308544 should be within the file!?

Comment: as far as I can see from the documentation, the size of the file should be read in the [gpfs_iattr_t](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.gpfs.v3r5.0.7.gpfs100.doc%2Fbl1adm_giatt.htm) structure (or the [gpfs_iattr64_t](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/topic/com.ibm.cluster.gpfs.v3r5.0.7.gpfs100.doc/bl1adm_giatt64.htm) one for x64) in the ia_size field.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting att. I'm not using gpfs_iattr_t. My code is very close to the example given at the top of gpfs_fcntl.h

Comment: Did you try to compare the size returned by `ls` and the size provided by `gpfs_iattr_t`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `offset` and `size` are `uint64_t`, unsigned integers. While the documentation for the struct `gpfsAccessRange_t` has the elements `start` and `length` as being `offset_t`, which could possibly be signed integers. Do you know how `offset_t` is defined?

I also note HDF5 uses `off_t`.

Comment: start and length are long long in my gpfs_fcntl.h

Answer (score 0):

I could not help but notice `/bgscratch`: if you are on a blue gene /Q system gpfs_fcntl() won't work unless you are running V1R2M1 or newer.   Older driver versions will not relay the gpfs_fcntl system call to the i/o nodes.